# Multi-line text in a .env file

Tags: vue.js

In vue, is there a way to have a value span multiple lines in an .env file.  Ex:

Instead of:

```
someValue=[{"someValue":"Here is a really really long piece which should be split into multiple lines"}]
```

I want to do something like:

```
someValue=`[{"someValue":"Here is a really
really long piece which
should be split into multiple lines"}]`
```

Doing the latter gives me a JSON parsing error if I try to do JSON.parse(someValue) in my code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: I'll write it as an answer since I can't seem to format a comment correctly.

Comment: It seems as JSON may be the culprit as it doesnt allow multiline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but I can't format a comment appropriately enough to get the point across so see if this will work:

```
someValue=[{"someValue":"Here is a really\
really long piece which\
should be split into multiple lines"}]
```

Where "\" should escape the newline similar to how you can write long bash commands while escaping the newline.  I'm not certain the `.env` interpreter will support it though.

---

### EDIT

Looks like this won't work.  This syntax was actually proposed, but I don't think it was incorporated.  See [motdotla/dotenv#333](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/333#issuecomment-422565889) (which is what Vue uses to parse `.env`).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work. I get an "unexpected token \ in JSON"

Comment: Yeah, turns out it won't work and the multi-delimiter of triple quotes doesn't work for dotenv :(

Answer (score 0):

Like @zero298 said, this isn't possible. Likely you could delimit the entry with a character that wouldn't show up normally in the text (^ is a good candidate), then parse it within the application using `string.replace('^', '\n');`